# Open application with lowered privileges

Tags: mac, bash, privileges

I have a mac installer which runs as root with pre and post install bash scripts.

At the end of the post install script I launch the application which inherits and opens as root. Is there a way I can lower the permissions back down to the user that ran the installer and then open the app?

Or a more hackish way I can set the app to open in some scheduler from the script, which then gets opened by the scheduler which would have the users permissions

Comment: No need to ask a new question, just edit this one.  I'll remove my comments so as not to confuse people.

Comment: Can you open the application using `open`, e.g. `open -a /Applications/MyApp.app`? If you're not installing an `.app`, you could check out output of `env`, it probably contains the actual user name. Just `su -u $username /path/to/app` or something like that.

Comment: I'm currently opening the app with `open "$APP_DIR"`. I guess a `su -u  "$username" "$APP_DIR"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged in as root you can use `su`:

```
/bin/su -c "open -a App.app" username
```